# If a string ends in a vowel of the following characters?

Tags: python, string

If a string doesn't end in `s`, `x`, `ch`, `sh` or if it doesn't ends in a vowel, then I need to add a 's'. This works for tell and eat but doesn't work for show. I am not able to figure out why.

This is the code I wrote:

```
if not re.match(".*(s|x|ch|sh)",s):
    if re.match(".*(a|e|i|o|u)",s):
        s = s+'s'
        return s
else:

    return s
```

Comment: Why not combine the regex for all of those characters into one regex? You're trying to identify words that end in none of those characters.

Comment: You are adding an 's' if the string *does* end in a vowel, not if it *doesn't* end in a vowel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `endswith` instead. It takes a single string, or a tuple of strings, and returns `True` if the string has any of the given arguments as a suffix.

```
cons = ('s', 'x', 'ch', 'sh')
vowels = ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
if not s.endswith(cons + vowels):
    s += 's'
return s
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `$` at the end of your regex if you only want to match the end of the string.